# Append a list from a different method type Java

Tags: java, list

I have two method with two different types and I would like to append the list from the first method to the second method. Methods as follows:

```
private List<Object> mergeData(List<Data1> tabList, List<Data2> tabListAnother){
   List<Object> mergeDataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

     mergeDataList = ListUtils.union(tabList, tabListAnother);

     return mergeDataList;
}

private List<Data1> getData(Some Parameters here........){

 List<Data1> data1List = new ArrayList<Data1>();


 Some code here adding to list all elements
 .......
 .......


 return data1List;
}
```

My question is how can I append ***mergeDataList*** to ***data1List*** so it returns in such a way that it outputs values of mergeDataList and data1List togethor in one return statement?

Help appreciated..

Comment: You can create an object that will hold both these list separately and return that object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can just call the method with the a call to `getData()` as one parameter and another list as the other.

```
   mergeData(getData(...), otherList)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, just do this:

```
data1List.addAll(mergeData(tabList,tabListAnother));
```